# Getting acquainted with people by observing?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

Let's say your in your family reunion, and it has been really a long time since your last show up(like 20 years and over) Can you say....

> ''I am still in a process of getting acquainted with the others **by observation''**.

P.s: Google answers can't just answer this. It says **get acquainted with** each other(get to know each other by talking or doing something together). BUT what if you are just observing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can* you say that?  Yes.  Is it *idiomatic*?  Not really.

First off, if you are meeting people you met before, but it's been some time, you get *reacquainted* with them.  Getting acquainted is for a first meeting.

> I was recently **reacquainted** with my high school English teacher, now long since retired.

*By observation* makes perfect sense, but in this context, it feels more natural to use the verb "to observe", or "to watch".

> He wasn't much of a party person, so at every gathering he would always stand around and **watch/observe** everyone from some distant corner.

Lastly, *in the process of* is a bit formal here.  It sounds like you're a scientist running an experiment.

> Ah, I am not being anti-social; rather I am **in the process of observing** the various interactions of the male and the female of the species *Studentis collegius* when copious amounts of ethyl alcohol are introduced to their diet.

All together, it might be more natural to say:

> I'm just going to **watch everyone** and **get reacquainted** with them that way.

Comment: Very nice! What a complete answer this is. I got nothing to ask. Thx man.